# Suppose $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = 1$. Is it true that for every $b>0$ we have $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{e^{bx}}{b}\left(f(x)\right)^2dx \ge 1 \; ? $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Suppose $a>0$ is such that
$$
\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = 1.
$$

Is it true that for every $b>0$ we have
$$
\int_{0}^{a}\frac{e^{bx}}{b}\left(f(x)\right)^2dx \ge 1 \; ?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\left(\int_0^a e^{bx}f^2(x)dx\right)\left(\int_0^a e^{-bx}dx\right)\ge\left(\int_0^a f(x)dx\right)^2=1.
$$

So
$$
\int_0^a e^{bx}f^2(x)dx\ge\frac{1}{\int_0^a e^{-bx}dx}=\frac{b}{1-e^{-ab}}>b.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not recognize Cauchy-Schwartz here. You answer is absolutely beautiful.